# Maximum bit-width to store a summation of M n-bit binary numbers

Tags: verilog, hardware, fpga, hdl

I am trying to find the formula to calculate the maximum bit-width required to contain a sum of M n-bit unsigned binary numbers. Thanks!

Comment: well if I add two one bit numbers it can take up to two bits.  If I add two two bit numbers it can worst case take three bits for the roll over.  If I add two three bit numbers worst case needs four...

Comment: If I add 1111 with 1 a four bit and a 1 bit it needs five as a result.  No different than decimal two one digit numbers can need two digit results, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum bit-width needed should be <strike>`ceil(log_2(M * (2^n - 1)))`</strike>.

Edit: Thanks to @MBurnham I realize now that it should be `floor(log_2(M * (2^n - 1))) + 1` instead.

Comment: Hm...I experimentally tested both formulas with wolfram alpha...seems like something's off still...

Comment: @bfung Off how?

Comment: for example, for M = 9 and n = 3, your proposed formula gives 7. When I add 0b111 for 9 times in wolfram alpha, the answer = 6b111111.

Comment: @bfung I get 6 for M=9 and n=3: [(link)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=floor(log_2(9+*+(2%5E3+-+1)))+%2B+1)

Comment: pardon me, my brackets were off. Thank you very much!

Comment: Although `floor(log_2(x)) + 1` is the number of bits required to hold x, I believe for the OP's question, the equality `ceil(log_2(M * (2^n - 1))) == floor(log_2(M * (2^n - 1))) + 1` holds true as long as `n > 1`. `n == 1` is a trivial case for binary addition. Do correct me, if otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming positive integers, you need floor(log2(x)) + 1 bits to store x. and the largest value the sum of m n-bit numbers can produce would be m * 2^n. 
So I believe the formula should be

```
floor(log2(m * 2^n)) + 1
```

bits.

Comment: The largest n-bit number is 2^n-1, not 2^n

Comment: @mbschenkel for just 1 number you are correct, but when you have a sum of two numbers, you can have values carry over to the next digit. so you need to store an extra bit for carry overs

Comment: You are already taking care of that with the factor `m`. If `B=2^n-1` is the biggest possible value of one, then `m * B` is the biggest possible sum of `m` summands, not `m * (B + 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

If I add 2 numbers the I need 1 bit more than the wider of the 2 numbers to store the result. So, if I add 2 n-bit numbers, I need n+1 bits to store the result.

```
if I add another n-bit number, I need (n+1)+1         bits to store the result (that's 3 n-bit numbers added so far)
if I add another n-bit number, I need ((n+1)+1)+1     bits to store the result (that's 4 n-bit numbers added so far)
if I add another n-bit number, I need (((n+1)+1)+1)+1 bits to store the result (that's 5 n-bit numbers added so far)
```

So, I think your formula is

```
n + M - 1
```

Comment: This is an upper bound, but not necessarily the minimum needed (despite the fact that OP is asking for max...). When adding two numbers, you don't use the full range: eg 1+1=10, not 11, 1+1+1=11 and does not use the 3rd bit at all. This is different for twos-complement negative numbers though.